# How to prove that $|\text{d}(x,y)-\text{d}(y,z) |\leq \text{d}(x,z)$ for some metric space $X$ for all elements $x,y,z \in X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

How to prove that $|\text{d}(x,y)-\text{d}(y,z) |\leq \text{d}(x,z)$ for some metric space $(X,d)$ for all elements $x,y,z \in X$

So far I have

$\text{d}(x,y)\leq \text{d}(x,z)+\text{d}(z,y)$ $\implies$ $\text{d}(x,y)-\text{d}(y,z) \leq \text{d}(x,z)$

So if $\text{d}(x,y)-\text{d}(y,z) \geq 0$ then it is equal to its own modulus and we are done.

But I'm not sure how to handle the case $\text{d}(x,y)-\text{d}(y,z) < 0$.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(y,z)\leq d(y,x) + d(x,z)\implies d(y,z)-d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)$ so you've got both sides.

Comment: Got it thanks! Never thought to just change the order of the letters to get the negative part. Cool trick!

Answer (score 1):

$d(x,y)−d(y,z)<0 \le d(x,z)$